# Reordenar variáveis jogando as vazias para o fim

Tags: php

Pretendo jogar para o fim da lista as variáveis que forem `null`. Isso faz parte da composição dos elementos da *view*, são blocos que podem vir vazios, e quero evitar ter que comparar as variáveis e reagrupar. Como posso refazer a ordem de exibição dos elementos na página, jogando os itens vazios pro fim?

No exemplo abaixo tenho as variáveis *A, B e C*, no caso normal faria um `foreach( $variavel_X as $linha )` e teria:

```
$variavel_A: nada aqui
$variavel_B: [ 'linha 1' , 'linha 2' , 'linha 3' ]
$variavel_C: [ 'linha 1' , 'linha 2' , 'linha 3' ]
```

---

O que preciso é exibir como na ordem abaixo, onde a variável vazia aparece por ultimo

```
$variavel_B: [ 'linha 1' , 'linha 2' , 'linha 3' ]
$variavel_C: [ 'linha 1' , 'linha 2' , 'linha 3' ]
$variavel_A: nada aqui
```

---

Pensei em jogar as variáveis em um array e reordenar com `arsort`, mas a função vai fazer a ordem crescente(a-z) ou decrescente(z-a), e isso não me interessa muito.

Comment: $variavel_A, B, C são posições de um array? `array('variavel_A' => array('linha1','linha2','linha3'))`

Comment: Nesse caso não são, mas posso jogar em um array se for necessário para resolver a questão. Sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando somente `foreach` poderia fazer:

```
foreach($array as $index => $valor){

    if(empty($valor)){
        unset($array[$index]);
        $array[$index] = $valor;
    }

}
```

Isso irá verificar se é vazio e irá remover da array e adicionar numa nova, que será incluído ao final da array, portanto considerando:

```
$array['a'] = [];
$array['b'] = ['linha1','linha2','linha3'];
$array['c'] = ['linha1','linha2','linha3'];
$array['d'] = null;
$array['e'] = ['linha1','linha2','linha3'];
$array['f'] = ['linha1','linha2','linha3'];
$array['g'] = '';
$array['h'] = ['linha1','linha2','linha3'];

foreach($array as $index => $valor){

    if(empty($valor)){
        unset($array[$index]);
        $array[$index] = $valor;
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
array(8) {
  ["b"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "linha1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "linha2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "linha3"
  }
  ["c"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "linha1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "linha2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "linha3"
  }
  ["e"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "linha1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "linha2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "linha3"
  }
  ["f"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "linha1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "linha2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "linha3"
  }
  ["h"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "linha1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "linha2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "linha3"
  }
  ["a"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["d"]=>
  NULL
  ["g"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/898b6ceb117379684194e6b82fb647135332e783)**

Answer (score 2):

Existem muitos [Algoritmos de ordenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para resolver o seu caso.

Mas vamos ao clássico [Bubble Sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

**Como funciona:**

Este algoritmo percorre a lista de itens ordenáveis do início ao fim, verificando a ordem dos elementos dois a dois, e trocando-os de lugar se necessário. Percorre-se a lista até que nenhum elemento tenha sido trocado de lugar na passagem anterior.

Então, vamos supor que você esteja utilizando um array bidimensional:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['a'] = array();
$arr['b'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['c'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['d'] = array();
$arr['e'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['f'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['g'] = array();
$arr['h'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
```

Criando esse código abaixo, estará verificando cada item para colocar os arrays vazios por último:

```
function bubble_sort(&$array){

        $tam = count($array);

        reset($array);//Aponta para primeira posição

        for($i = 0; $i<$tam; $i++){
            for($j = 0; $j<($tam-1); $j++){             
                //Pega dados da posição atual
                $current_position = each($array);
                //Pega dados da proxima posição
                $next_position = each($array);
                prev($array); //Volta posição   

                if(empty($current_position['value']) &&
                   !empty($next_position['value'])){              
                    $array[$current_position['key']] = $next_position['value'];
                    $array[$next_position['key']] = $current_position['value'];                                 
                }

            }
            reset($array);//Aponta para primeira posição
        }

    }

    bubble_sort($arr);

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Entrada:

> {"a":[],"b":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"c":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"d":[],"e":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"f":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"g":[],"h":["linha1","linha2","linha3"]}

Saída:

> {"a":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"b":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"c":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"d":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"e":["linha1","linha2","linha3"],"f":[],"g":[],"h":[]}

Comment: Estava pensando em algo mais simples, cheguei ao seguinte: filter em cada elemento do array, depois filtro o array - terei somente os índices com valores - e depois combino com o array antigo. O resultado é o mesmo, valores nulos no final. [Dê uma olhada](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf419a13f734b1c8a87d840b6b25a2b4b71e5372)

Comment: Foi um primeiro teste, ainda não sei se é totalmente exato. Mas TKS pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

> **[uasort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uasort.php)** — *Ordena um array utilizando uma função de comparação definida pelo usuário e mantendo as associações entre chaves e valores.*

Veja um exemplo de como utilizar com base em sua questão:

```html
<?php

// Definição dos arrays
$arr = array();
$arr['a'] = array();
$arr['b'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3', 'linha4');
$arr['c'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['d'] = array();
$arr['e'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['f'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');
$arr['g'] = array();
$arr['h'] = array('linha1','linha2','linha3');

// Função personalizada para ordenar os arrays
// 0 quer dizer igual, -1 joga para o início e 1 para o final.
function sortArrays($a, $b) {
    
    if(count($a) == count($b)){
     return 0;
    }

    return (count($a) > count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Reordena os arrays
uasort($arr, 'sortArrays');

// Imprime o array ordenado
print_r($arr);

?>
```

Resultado final:

```html
Array
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha1
            [1] => linha2
            [2] => linha3
            [3] => linha4
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha1
            [1] => linha2
            [2] => linha3
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha1
            [1] => linha2
            [2] => linha3
        )

    [f] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha1
            [1] => linha2
            [2] => linha3
        )

    [h] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha1
            [1] => linha2
            [2] => linha3
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
        )

    [g] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Uma outra aternativa seria mudar para `function sortArrays($a, $b) { return count($b) <=> count($a); }` faria exatamente a mesma coisa, com menos código.

Comment: @Inkeliz, sim, obrigado pela dica, mas só um lembrete, isto valo para o PHP 7 em diante, versões abaixo não funcionaria.